# remove rows on jquery datatable based on radiobutton selection visualforce

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4, visualforce

I've been searching around and cant find out how to make a data table change dynamically with a radio button select value. I'm using bootstrap as well in order to make things look better.

I wish I had more to give you but I'm new and pretty lost even though I've been googling for a couple of hours. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my javascript with jquery

```
<script>
var j$=jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function(){
 //BEGINNING OF DATA TABLE
    var titleTable = j$('[id$="titletable"]').DataTable({
        "order": [[1,"asc"]],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 0,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-info'>Add to Queue</button>"
        } ]

    });//end of Data Table

  j$('[id$=radioButtonValues]').on("change",function(event){

       //titleTable.rows().remove() where 
       //j$('[id$=radioButtonValues]').val() only matches data in the 3rd column

    });
</script>
```

This is my visualforce code

```
<apex:PageBlock >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Display Games By Console!" id="consoleDisplayLabel"/>
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!consoleValue}" id="radioButtonValues" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!consoleOptions}" id="radioButtonOptions"/>

        </apex:selectRadio>   
    </apex:PageBlock>
<apex:PageBlock >

        <table id="titletable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Queue</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Console</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <apex:repeat value="{!titles}" var="title" >
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{!title.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!title.Console__r.Name}</td>

                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>

            </tbody>
        </table>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

And this is my controller

```
public class AdminPageController 
{

 public String consoleValue {get;set;}

 private String sortOrder = 'Name';
 List<Console__c> theseConsole = new List<Console__c>([Select id,name FROM Console__c  ]);

public AdminPageController(){
        consoleValue = 'ALL';   
}//constructor

 public List<SelectOption> getconsoleOptions(){

    List<SelectOption> consoleOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    consoleOptions.add(new SelectOption('ALL', 'ALL'));
    for(Console__c a : theseConsoles)
    consoleOptions.add(new SelectOption(a.name,a.name));
    return consoleOptions;

}
public List<Title__C> gettitles()
{
    List <Title__C> titlebyConsole = new List<Title__c>();
    if(consoleValue != 'All'){
        String soql = 'SELECT Name, Console__r.Name FROM Title__c WHERE Title__C.Console__r.Name = :consoleValue' + ' ORDER BY ' +sortOrder;
        titlebyConsole = Database.query(soql);
    }
    else{
        String soql2 = 'SELECT Name, Console__r.Name  from Title__c ORDER BY ' +sortOrder;
        titlebyConsole = Database.query(soql2);
    }
    return titlebyConsole;
}//end of Get titles
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the impression that you need to hide and not remove the row. If I am correct, you need to implement a custom search by extending DataTables. Here's an example:

```
$(function() {
  var table = $('#titletable').DataTable();
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    reset();
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      //does this row contain the text of the value selected in the radio button?
      return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).text().indexOf(selection) >= 0;
    });
    table.draw();
  });

  function reset() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    table.draw();  
  }
  $('#reset').click(reset);    
});
```

And here's a [full fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1c9frq1f/) with some fake data.

If you need to remove the rows, then you need to know that there's no way to re-display the row again unless you maintain a reference to it and re-add it to DataTables. It seems that you are pretty clear on how the API works for removing rows.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for letting me know about the remove rows.  That could have been very bad. I've implemented it on my page and it works perfectly!  I'm going to go read up about extending DataTables to really understand it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to do an exact match to the radio values? 
I've tried searching the Datatables website/forum and messing around with regular expressions with fnFilter but I'm getting no-where.

Comment: @ToddDay98 you can do exact match by changing `return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).text().indexOf(selection) >= 0` to  `return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).text() == selection`

Comment: Thank you again so much for your help! 
I was finally able to use your help to get just what I needed. 
I used this 
`j$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                
                if(selection == "ALL")
                {
                    return j$(titleTable.row(dataIndex).node());
                }else{
                    if(j$(titleTable.row(dataIndex).node().cells[2]).text() == selection)
                     {
                          return j$(titleTable.row(dataIndex).node()).text();
     }
}`